# How to optimize these jquery functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, user-experience, pagespeed

I'm working on a javascript intensive user-interface application. (At least it's intensive for me, it's my first serious javascript project).

I have a few jquery functions going whenever a `div` is rolled over or `mouseout`. For example there are some `divs` which are draggable objects, and so when they are `mouseover`ed, the cursor must look ready to move. But my interface so slow that my boss thinks my code isn't working, when in fact it is, but it's just slow and so the user has to sometimes wait upto 2-3 seconds for the cursor to look as expected, or for a `div` to look as expected. Just an example. My code is something like below, I can't reproduce it entirely or properly since my company has copyrights on this, but just to give a clear idea of the way I'm doing things:

```
$.fn.extend({
    mouseoverBox: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);   
                if(!$this.hasClass('ready')) 
                {   if($this.hasClass('activated'))
                    {
                        $this.removeClass('activated');
                    }
                    $this.addClass('ready');
                }
                var img_id = $this.children('.theimg').attr('id');
                //someitem.children('somechildren').remove();
                //someitem.append(somemenu div)
                //$this.draggable();
                //$this.resizable();
                if($this.hasClass('unlocked'))
                {
                    $this.draggable( "option", "disabled", false );
                    $this.resizable( "option", "disabled", false );
                }
                $this.bindUnlock();
            });
     }
// end mouseoverBox
});
```

Now this is just the mouseoverBox function, which is triggered like `myBox.mouseoverBox()`. on the mouse over event. Then of course this plugin is calling `bindUnlock()` which has simple operations like changing classes and adding classes to a menu. Also, before any mouseover, there's usually been a `mouseout` out of another `div`... so as you can see there's a lot of stuff happening. There aren't usually more than 10 interactive `divs` on at any one moment though. How can I optimize this kind of code? I haven't given every specific but trust me most of the relevant is pretty much just like this.

I've already gzipped my javascript, css, images and fonts. I also tried minifying using the Yahoo Compressor but it actually bloated one of my files instead of compressing it.

Comment: Might be best suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the look and feel, why not just do this in the CSS using hover pseudo classes, e.g.:

```
div.draggable:hover { 
    background:yellow;
    cursor:ponter;
}
```

That way all your class changing code could potentially be cut down.

Comment: but would that be compatible across Chrome/FF/IE (at least back till IE8)?

Comment: Okay, I've checked, and it is pretty compatible. But my code isn't that simple. For example, it's not simply on `hover` that the class changes. It's only when my `div` has a specific class (eg. `activated`) that certain CSS would kick in.

Comment: Then add your hover pseudo class to the activated CSS class, e.g. div.activated:hover.